# Shell script that takes the PID as the input and get the threads associated with each PID and writes it to a file. Can someone help or guide?

Tags: bash, shell

Shell script that takes the `PID` as the input and get the threads associated with each `PID` and writes it to a file. Can someone help or guide?

I am using `top -H -b -n 1 | grep java > /path/top.log` to capture `PID`'s and add them in top.log file

Also I think `top -H -p <PID>` can help me to get the threads associated with specific `PID`.

How can I automate it using shell script?

Comment: Can you show us your own attempts ?

Comment: `ps -T -p <pid>` works ?

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -p <PID> -o cmd
```

and to see pid:

```
pgrep java
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the process name based on name:

```
pgrep java
```

Get the thread using the /proc filesystem (on linux kernel)

```
ls /proc/$(pgrep java)/task
```

If you have several java PID, use a `for` loop:

```
for i in $(pgrep java); do echo $i; ls /proc/$i/task; echo; done
```

Info: `man 5 proc`:

> /proc/[pid]/task (since Linux 2.6.0-test6)
>
> This is a directory that contains one subdirectory for each thread in the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oliv, it served my purpose

Answer (score 1):

> I am using `top -H -b -n 1 | grep java > /path/top.log` to capture
>   `PID`'s and add them in top.log file

If you just want all `java` threads: `ps -LCjava`